# Firebase AuthStateListener throwing NullPointerException

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I keep getting this weird error and I can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method
>   'void
>   com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$AuthStateListener.onAuthStateChanged(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                  at com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$1.run(Unknown Source)

```
package com.workoutwager.headshot;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
 import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mSignUpBtn;
private EditText mEmailEdit;
private EditText mPasswordEdit;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthState;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mSignUpBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signUpBtn);
    mEmailEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
    mPasswordEdit = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mAuthState = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
                //Not signed in
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
            }
            else {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            }
        }
    };


    }
@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthState);
}
}
```

Comment: It's helpful to see the entire stack trace instead of just the exception.

Comment: Also, when `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null` is true, the user is logged-in.  Why are you starting `LoginActivity`?

Answer (score 0):

If `firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()==null` means user is curently not logged in. So if this is true then it should goto `LoginActivity`.

### Hence your code should be:

```
if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()==null){
   //Not signed in
   Intent loginIntent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
   loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   startActivity(loginIntent);
}
```